# Iterate two or more lists / numpy arrays... and compare each item with each other and avoid loops in python

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, scipy

I am new to python  and my problem is the following:

I have defined a function `func(a,b)` that return a value, given two input values.

Now I have my data stored in lists or numpy arrays `A,B`and would like to use `func` for every combination. (A and B have over one million entries)

ATM i use this snippet:

```
for p in A:
  for k in B:
    value = func(p,k)
```

This takes really really a lot of time.

So i was thinking that maybe something like this:

```
C=(map(func,zip(A,B)))
```

But this method only works pairwise... Any ideas?

Thanks for help

Comment: Your `func()` is symmetric, right? `func(a,b)` == `func(b,a)`?

Comment: Good spot @Aman, that should mean only half of the work has to be done.

Comment: @madzone: What kind of comparison are you doing with these pairs?

Comment: We need more information about `func` and about what you plan to do with the result. Are you trying to store all the results at once in a trillion-item matrix? (Good luck!) Or do you just need to iterate over each result without storing any of them?

Comment: @PhilH, its just a numerical integration with these two numbers of `A` and `B` as borders
@senderle, I need to store the results and visualize it, e.g. with pyplot

Comment: @madzone: a trillion values? You don't want to store *or* calculate a trillion values, let alone attempt to visualize them.

Comment: @madzone: do any of the values in A and/or B recur? Are they integers or float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose, itertools.product does what you need:

```
from itertools import product

pro = product(A,B)
C = map(lambda x: func(*x), pro)
```

so far as it is generator it doesn't require additional memory

Comment: This calls `f(A[0], B[0])`, `f(A[1], B[1])`, and so on. Probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @adray, I think you want combinations_with_replacement, as apparently func(a,b) == func(b,a).

Comment: @
Works really good after I subdivided the arrays. Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

## First issue

You need to calculate the output of `f` for many pairs of values. The "standard" way to speed up this kind of loops (calculations) is to make your function `f` accept (NumPy) arrays as input, and do the calculation on the whole array at once (ie, no looping as seen from Python). Check any NumPy tutorial to get an introduction.

## Second issue

If `A` and `B` have over a million entries each, there are one trillion combinations. For 64 bits numbers, that means you'll need 7.3 TiB of space just to store the result of your calculation. Do you have enough *hard drive* to just store the result?

## Third issue

If `A` and `B` where much smaller, in your particular case you'd be able to do this:

```
values = f(*meshgrid(A, B))
```

[`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) returns the cartesian product of `A` and `B`, so it's simply a way to generate the points that have to be evaluated.

## Summary

- You need to use NumPy effectively to avoid Python loops. (Or if all else fails or they can't easily be vectorized, write those loops in a compiled language, for instance by using [Cython](http://www.cython.org/))
- Working with terabytes of data is hard. Do you really need that much data?
- Any solution that calls a function `f` 1e12 times in a loop is bound to be slow, specially in CPython (which is the default Python implementation. If you're not really sure and you're using NumPy, you're using it too).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer.Unfortunately CPython is not an option atm.
What does meshgrid exactly do? Can you please explain a bit further?

Comment: Ok, you seem a bit confused (I understand that, and I'm sorry for using so much terminology in my answer, but you have a few intertwined issues right now). I'll try to expand my answer.

Comment: Hi, thx @jorgeca.
As you suggested I also try to avoid explicit loops and did write all my functions so that I can run them on entire numpy.arrays.
I can make subsamples of my arrays and ran the code in pieces, that's a good point. 
Still the calculations take too much time.. thnx anyway

Comment: @madzone I *strongly* suspect you're doing way too many calculations. I'm repeating myself, but how do you expect to store the result? What kind of machine are you going to use to plot over 7 TiB of data using matplotlib? Using a HiRes display at 200 ppi and 1 pixel per calculated value, you'd need a display of over 160 m^2 to see the whole thing!!

Comment: @ jorgeca
I store the results and plot in a histogram.
I will try list comprehensions I let you know the outcome.

Comment: @madzone I'm afraid we're not understanding each other. Please, if something in my previous comment doesn't make sense to you *ask* us. But I'm absolutely sure that a list comprehension with a trillion doubles inside is not going to work. Again, you're trying to generate a HUGE amount of data that you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

One million times one million is one trillion. Calling `f` one trillion times will take a while.

Unless you have a way of reducing the number of values to compute, you can't do better than the above.

Comment: NumPy lets you push the loops (and their overhead, including function calls) down to C, so it's much faster. Still, one trillion floats are quite a lot...

Answer (score 1):

If you use NumPy, you should definitely look the [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function which is designed for this kind of problems...

Comment: Hi @Pierre GM,
as much as I understood np.vectorize is similar to the python map function. If I vectorize a function and call it with two arrays, it will work as follows:
`f(A[0], B[0]), f(A[1], B[1])`. But I need to call in every combination.
thx